# Display a RadioGroup's items in a table like form

Tags: android, checkbox

I'm trying to place a set of Checkboxes within the same RadioGroup in a tabular fashion.

Something like this:

```
  [Check1] [Check2]
  [Check3] [Check4]
```

I tried to have a couple of TableRow objects within the RadioGroup, but that removes the "group behaviour" and allows more than one Checkbox can be selected at the same time.

I am able to put all the items on a single line (by setting the RadioGroup's "orientation" to "horizontal") but not in a grid like style.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: [Try processing the RadioButtons without the use of RadioGroup.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332042/setting-up-a-radiogroup-programmatically/7019673#7019673

Comment: Here is a [MultiRadioGroup](https://github.com/yuxingxin/MultiRadioGroup).