# setting up a RadioGroup programmatically

Tags: android

I'd like to create a custom `View` which contains a `RadioGroup`. Inside of the `RadioGroup` I'd like the `RadioButtons` to be set up so that the first `RadioButton` is at the top left, the 2nd one is below that, the third to the right of the 1st one and the 4th one underneath that. In other words, I want to create a group where the radiobuttons are laid out in a square of sorts. I think if I set the orientation of the group to be vertical, then all the radiobuttons will be in a straight line. If, on the other hand, I set the orientation to horizontal, then, again, the radiobuttons will all be in a straight line, going horizontal. Is there a way to do what I want or am I forced to set up two separate `RadioGroups`, both to horizontal orientation?

Comment: you can use the RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout

Comment: @Pratik hows that going to help? That will help me set up the Group relative to something else, but what about the buttons relative to each other?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try processing the `RadioButtons` without the use of `RadioGroup`.

Wire-up the individual `RadioButtons` and hold them in an `ArrayList<RadioButton>`.

```
List<RadioButton> radioButtons = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();

radioButtons.add( (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.button1) );        
radioButtons.add( (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.button2) );
radioButtons.add( (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.button3) );
etc.
```

Set an `OnCheckedChangeListener` for each `RadioButton`.

```
for (RadioButton button : radioButtons){

    button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) processRadioButtonClick(buttonView);
        }   
    });

}
```

Then create a method to uncheck the unselected `RadioButtons`.

```
private void processRadioButtonClick(CompoundButton buttonView){

    for (RadioButton button : radioButtons){

        if (button != buttonView ) button.setChecked(false);
    }

}
```

Using this approach, the `RadioButtons` can be located anywhere within the XML layout.

Comment: Awesome answer Matt, Can you please explain how to get Id of selected radio button, I tried but  I failed. Waiting for your valuable answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass from [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) and override [onLayout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#onLayout%28boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an example of what the override would look like to accomplish wha I'm trying to do?

Comment: you could figure out how to implement onLayout from Roman Nurik's dashboard view: https://gist.github.com/882650