# android- radio button in different linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have dynamically created LinearLayout and radiobutton in each linearlayout... but i want to group those radioButton, but I am not being able to do that...

```
LinearLayout linearlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.player_point_entry);

    TextView[] TVplayer = new TextView[number_of_player];
    EditText[] ETpoint = new EditText[number_of_player];
    EditText[] ETmaal = new EditText[number_of_player];
    RadioButton[] won = new RadioButton[number_of_player];
    RadioGroup RG_won = new RadioGroup(this);

    LinearLayout[] dyn_linearLayout = new LinearLayout[number_of_player];

    for(int i =0; i<number_of_player; i++)
    {
        dyn_linearLayout[i] = new LinearLayout(this);
        dyn_linearLayout[i].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        dyn_linearLayout[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        dyn_linearLayout[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TVplayer[i] = new TextView(this);
                TVplayer[i].setText(player_name[i]);
                TVplayer[i].setTypeface(face);
                TVplayer[i].setTextSize(15);
                TVplayer[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                TVplayer[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

            ETpoint[i] = new EditText(this);
                ETpoint[i].setHint("Point");
                ETpoint[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(70, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

            ETmaal[i] = new EditText(this);
                ETmaal[i].setHint("Maal");
                ETmaal[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(70, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

            won[i] = new RadioButton(this);
                won[i].setChecked(true);
                won[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                won[i].setChecked(false);

            dyn_linearLayout[i].addView(TVplayer[i]);
            dyn_linearLayout[i].addView(ETpoint[i]);
            dyn_linearLayout[i].addView(ETmaal[i]);
            dyn_linearLayout[i].addView(won[i]);

            linearlayout.addView(dyn_linearLayout[i]);

    }
```

Please help me... above code lets me add RadioButton to different LinearLayout but can group them...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a RadioGroup programmatically. Check out this question: [setting up a RadioGroup programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332042/setting-up-a-radiogroup-programmatically)

Comment: awesome dude.. I haven't tried yet but i guess it will solve my problem. thanks...

Comment: :: can you tell me how can i get the id of checked radio button.

Comment: Use RadioGroup's getCheckedRadioButtonId()