# Android RadioGroup get the RadioButton index

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I created a RadioGroup programmatically and added in it some RadioButton (they can be 1 or 2 or 3, it dependes from the database).
I tried this code but it crashes when I try to get the RadioButton selected ID

```
    final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroupTeamId);
    for (int i = 0; i < teamID.size(); i++)
    {
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getActivity());
        radioButton.setText(i);
        if(i == 0)
            radioButton.setChecked(true);
        radioButton.setId(i);
        radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
    }
    radioGroup.invalidate();

    ........
    ........

    builder1.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {
            int teamId = radioGroup..getCheckedRadioButtonId(); // Here the app crashes

            .........
        }
    });
```

XML file:

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroupTeamId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </RadioGroup>
```

Log:

```
    07-23 18:49:40.920: E/AndroidRuntime(5437): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-23 18:49:40.920: E/AndroidRuntime(5437): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
    07-23 18:49:40.920: E/AndroidRuntime(5437):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:247)
    07-23 18:49:40.920: E/AndroidRuntime(5437):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3473)
    07-23 18:49:40.920: E/AndroidRuntime(5437):     at com.example.apptesina.FragmentFindOperations.selectedItem(FragmentFindOperations.java:185)
    07-23 18:49:40.920: E/AndroidRuntime(5437):     at com.example.apptesina.FragmentFindOperations.access$1(FragmentFindOperations.java:154)
    07-23 18:49:40.920: E/AndroidRuntime(5437):     at com.example.apptesina.FragmentFindOperations$1.onItemClick(FragmentFindOperations.java:148)
    07-23 18:49:40.920: E/AndroidRuntime(5437):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
    07-23 18:49:40.920: E/AndroidRuntime(5437):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
    07-23 18:49:40.920: E/AndroidRuntime(5437):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
    07-23 18:49:40.920: E/AndroidRuntime(5437):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
    07-23 18:49:40.920: E/AndroidRuntime(5437):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    07-23 18:49:40.920: E/AndroidRuntime(5437):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    07-23 18:49:40.920: E/AndroidRuntime(5437):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    07-23 18:49:40.920: E/AndroidRuntime(5437):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    07-23 18:49:40.920: E/AndroidRuntime(5437):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-23 18:49:40.920: E/AndroidRuntime(5437):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    07-23 18:49:40.920: E/AndroidRuntime(5437):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    07-23 18:49:40.920: E/AndroidRuntime(5437):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    07-23 18:49:40.920: E/AndroidRuntime(5437):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are adding radio button via code what getCheckedRadioButtonId does is look for radio buttons resource id, which can be done when you add Radio button in xml layout.

See [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/)

```
 <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroupTeamId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_male" 
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_female" />

</RadioGroup>
```

Or Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7019673/713778) post

You can manually keep track of the currently selected item or create a click listener on each radio button.

Comment: Is there a way to use getCheckedRadioButtonId in my case? If I use xml layouts I need to create a lot of them, respectively with 1 or 2 or 3 ...

Comment: I have edited my answer, check this post -  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7019673/713778